# I want to update my picture boxes in userform with really bigs tasks without the form freezing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I tried backgroundworker but doesnt work, as i need to update my form with each step and the backgroundworker.progresschanged only works as percentage. and if it were for only one step it could have been done with one. I also thought about making 10 different background workers and doing it that way. but then how would i cacth the exceptions and show the exceptions. and each of my try statements implements excel functions and excel workbook functions. which is also not possible in background worker.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   btnStart.Click

    pctrBoxStep1.Image = My.Resources.Yellow1
    lblStep1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    workbook.Activate()
    Try
        'some stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
        int = -1
        pctrBoxStep1.Image = My.Resources.red
        lblStep1.BackColor = Color.Red
        MessageBox.Show("There was an Error!!" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
    'Repeat for 9 more steps

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and each of my try statements implements excel functions and excel workbook functions. which is also not possible in background worker.

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098995/net-com-assembly-interacting-with-excel-via-backgroundworker) This is the only reason I can think of why you'd be having trouble using Excel functions in a BackgroundWorker.

> I also thought about making 10 different background workers and doing it that way. but then how would i cacth the exceptions and show the exceptions.

From what you describe, this is probably the approach I would take. It sounds like you don't need to track the progress percentage of each worker at all. In that case, I would use the `ReportProgress` call *only* in your `Catch` statements. Something like:

```
Private Sub bgwStep1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwStep1.DoWork
    Try
        'some stuff
    Catch ex As Exception
        bgwStep1.ReportProgress(0)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) 'Precautionary
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub bgwStep1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwStep1.ProgressChanged
    int = -1
    pctrBoxStep1.Image = My.Resources.red
    lblStep1.BackColor = Color.Red
    bgwStep1.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgw1.RunWorkerCompleted
    bgw2.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Each BackgroundWorker must have its `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property set to `True`.
- `Sleep` is called to make sure the UI thread has time to cancel the BackgroundWorker before it completes.
- Keeping the data from the exception thrown is a little more complicated, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044460/unhandled-exceptions-in-backgroundworker) illustrates how to do so should you decide to go that route.